# Django post it's empty

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

i'm using Django rest framework 
this is my Serializer:

```
class IncentiveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags=TagSerializer(many=True,  read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Incentive
        fields = ('schemeName', 'schemeID','text','typeID','typeName','status','ordinal','tags','modeID',
        'groupIncentive','condition')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags',[])
        incentive = super(IncentiveSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        for tag in tags_data:
            if tag is not None:
                tags=Tag.objects.create(incentiveID=incentive, **tag)

        # Ignores tags without a tagId
        tags_ids = [tag["tagID"] for tag in tags_data if "tagID" in tag]

        if tags_ids:
            tags = Tag.objects.filter(tagId__in=tags_ids)
            incentive.tags.add(*tags)
         else:
             incentive.tags.add(*tags)

        return incentive
```

all the time that i'm tring POST the tags_data is empty [ { } ] 
this is what i'm trying to post:

```
{
    "schemeName": "ghjgkj", 
    "schemeID": 2314, 
    "text": "asgas", 
    "typeID": 123, 
    "typeName": "asga", 
    "status": false, 
    "ordinal": null, 
    "tags": [{"tagID":1232,"tagName":"DO"}], 
    "modeID": 123, 
    "groupIncentive": false, 
    "condition": "asdfga"
}
```

i tried to print into a file the tags_data and it's always empty
what i'm doing wrong? (i'm printing into a file with json.dumps)
how can i get the tags parameters form the posting? is there something wrong with my posting?

**EDIT**:
this is `tagserializer`:

```
    class TagSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Tag
            fields = ('tagID', 'tagName')
```

Comment: What is your `TagSerializer`?

Comment: i added TagSerialzier code

Comment: Are you sure that `TagSerializer` is `Serializer` and not a `ModelSerializer`? You used `model` in class Meta.

Comment: im not sure, but this make any difference?

Comment: @SamRad Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!! it's work !!!! i can't believe it i tried everything but this!

Comment: @samrad can you explain me what is the difference?

Comment: `ModelSerializer` is bound to django model. Hence, when you set the  `model` in Meta class along with `fields`, it'll look for fields on the model. But if you use `Serializer`, you have to explicitly define each field on serializer. Like, `tagID = serializer.CharField()`

Comment: further reading: [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)